# Scala reduce IDs from multiple tuples into one single ID

Tags: scala, reduce

I have a vector `vecTest1` with tuples inside as below, 6 element per tuple with the first element a key. And I would like to go through an algorithm to decide one single BAB.

[image]

And this is how I do it

```
var strBAB:String="BAB1"
var intNumbBAB=vecTest1(0)._6

for (a<-1 to vecTest1.length-1){

intNumbBAB=intNumbBAB+vecTest1(a)._6
val douAAE = (vecTest1(a-1)._1 - vecTest1(a-1)._2) / vecTest1(a-1)._1
val douAAE1 = (vecTest1(a-1)._1 - vecTest1(a-1)._2 + vecTest1(a-1)._3) / vecTest1(a-1)._1
val douAAE2 = (vecTest1(a)._1 - vecTest1(a)._2 - vecTest1(a-1)._3) / vecTest1(a)._1

  if(douAAE1<=.04 && douAAE2>douAAE){
    if (vecTest1(a)._6>intNumbBAB) strBAB=vecTest1(a)._1
    else strBAB=vecTest1(a-1)._1
  }
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this? I am new to Scala but this seems to be reducing. So is it possible to do it with a reduce in a neater manner?

Comment: Have a look to `zipWithIndex` and `foldLeft`

Comment: Also `sliding(2)` might help

Comment: I wonder if your code would be cleaner if you use a multidimensional array instead.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to identify a particular tuple by processing the sequence of the elements in turn. Any kind of such loop can be converted into some form of recursion, which is the idiomatic approach in *Scala* as a language for *functional programming*.

Here's a version written as a function that returns the key value sought.

Note that I'm using a type (`BAB`) to represent the tuple more succinctly. I've also generalized the method so that it works with any `Seq` of values (a `Vector` is a type of `IndexedSeq`, which is a type of `Seq`); but indexing of values is not actually necessary in this case. Finally, note that there are no `var`s in this implementation.

I have had to change your code because negation (`-`) and division (`/`) operations are not permitted on strings, so I've replaced references to `_1` (a `String` value) with `_2` (a `Double` value), replaced `_2` with `_3`, and replaced `_3` with `_4`. I apologize if this isn't what you wanted, but your code doesn't compile and I don't know the purpose behind the calculations in your code.

```scala
import scala.annotation.tailrec

type BAB = (String, Double, Double, Double, Double, Int)
def findBAB(babs: Seq[BAB]): String = {

  // Tail-recursive helper method to find the best BAB.
  //
  // "best" identifies the key of the best BAB found so far; "num" is
  // whatever quantity intNumbBAB represents in your original code; "last"
  // is the last BAB considered; and "rem" is the remainder of BAB's to be
  // examined, which may be empty.
  @tailrec
  def find(best: String, num: Int, last: BAB, rem: Seq[BAB]): String = {

    // If the remainder is empty, then return the best key. We're done.
    if(rem.isEmpty) best
    
    // Otherwise, perform another iteration.
    else {

      // Get head tuple of remainder, as the current BAB.
      val cur = rem.head

      // Calculations.
      val newNum = num + cur._6
      val douAAE = (last._2 - last._3) / last._2
      val douAAE1 = (last._2 - last._3 + last._4) / last._2
      val douAAE2 = (cur._2 - cur._3 - last._4) / cur._2

      // Do we have a new best BAB key?
      val newBest = if(douAAE1 <= 0.04 && douAAE2 > douAAE) {
        if (cur._6 > newNum) cur._1
        else last._1
      }
      else best

      // Perform the next iteration.
      find(newBest, newNum, cur, rem.tail)
    }
  }

  // Start the ball rolling by initializing the search.
  find(babs.head._1, babs.head._6, babs.head, babs.tail)
}
```

The above is a fairly manual approach, which demonstrates the recursion, but it's arguably not an improvement over what you currently have.

Here's another version using the `foldLeft` *higher-order function*, which is a little terser but also perhaps more unintuitive:

```scala
type BAB = (String, Double, Double, Double, Double, Int)
def findBAB(babs: Seq[BAB]): String = {

  // Perform a foldLeft on the tail of the sequence.
  //
  // The "zero" value is a tuple of the key of the first BAB, the "num"
  // value, plus the first BAB itself
  val result = babs.tail.foldLeft((babs.head._1, babs.head._6, babs.head)) {

    // Break open the tuple arguments.
    case ((best, num, last), cur) => {

      // Calculations.
      val newNum = num + cur._6
      val douAAE = (last._2 - last._3) / last._2
      val douAAE1 = (last._2 - last._3 + last._4) / last._2
      val douAAE2 = (cur._2 - cur._3 - last._4) / cur._2

      // Do we have a new best BAB key?
      val newBest = if(douAAE1 <= 0.04 && douAAE2 > douAAE) {
        if (cur._6 > newNum) cur._1
        else last._1
      }
      else best

      // Return a tuple with the values for the next iteration.
      (newBest, newNum, cur)
    }
  }

  // Return the first value of the tuple result (the BAB key).
  result._1
}
```

A `reduce` operation isn't possible, because information other than just the values in the sequence are required (the key of the best BAB and the mysterious "num" value).

I would also consider using a `case class` instead of a tuple, so that the values in each BAB can be named, rather than referenced by number. For example:

```scala
final case class BAB(key: String, v1: Double, v2: Double, v3: Double,
v4: Double, num: Int)
```

Case classes have added functionality for little overhead.

Comment: Thanks for the input. The mysterious 'num'? Everything used to decide the best BAB comes from this Vector. You meant intNumbBAB in my code?